# Which view controller should I use?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I would like to create a social media app with 4 main pages. 
It looks something like this. [image]

The connection arrow is mean swipe direction.
However, I m not sure use what kind of controller to suit my situation. I watched some tutorial like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_daE3IL_1s). I am not sure using `UIPageViewController`, `UIScrollView or customize a self controller. Also, if I use UIPageviewController` how can I set the "middle" (the search) page always showing first? Also, if I use `UIScrollView`  or `UIPageViewController` how can I swipe top like the image above?

Comment: I don't think you are going to benefit by using a page view controller. It'll probably be a lot of working around behaviors. I would probably just have a main controller with an embedded container view controller which gets animated in depending on the swipe.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by using UIPageViewController or use 3rd party Library like [this](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu).
To make your search view as root view controller just select search view in storyboard and check "Is initial View Controller" in inspector.